# Как связать форму сайта с Битрикс 24?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Есть аккаунт битрикса 24 и есть сайт с одной формой.
Сейчас при отправке формы, данные отправляются в базу.
Задача такова, нужно одновременно с добавлением записи в базу, отправлять информацию в битрикс 24 в виде нового лида и с аналитикой.
В общем, есть ли статьи для чайников, так как совершенно не знаю битрикса?:(
И по какому методу это вообще возможно сделать, или если у вас был опыт с таким?
 Был бы признателен в помощи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам подойдет [создание приложения](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=05377) третьего-типа для портала и создание лида с помощью [REST API Битрикс24](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/).
Также вы можете воспользоваться функционалом Битрикс24 под названием [CRM-формы](https://www.bitrix24.ru/blogs/community_blog/sozdaem-crmformu-za-minutu-bez-sayta-i-programmista.php). Вы можете в Битрикс24 создать форму, которую с помощью js-кода можно потом разместить на сайте и данные которой с аналитикой сразу будут писаться в лид. CRM-формы можно найти в Битрикс24 в левом меню в разделе CRM в пункте CRM-формы.

Answer (score 1):

Создание лидов по API - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/chaos/crm-sozdanie-lidov-iz-drugikh-servisov.php
Помимо системных полей этим способом можно передать и пользовательские поля.

А в CRM-формах, на текущий момент, возможна передача параметров лишь на этапе генерации формы на стороне сервера, а значения переменных, назначаемые в процессе работы пользователя со страницей, передать не получится.